On the map $\operatorname{Top}(X,Y \times Z) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Top}(X,Y) \times \operatorname{Top}(X,Z)$
Disclaimer: We define a topological space $X$ to be compact if every open cover has a finite subcover, but $X$ is otherwise allowed to be arbitrary.
I have been faced with the following problem:
Let $X, Y, Z$ be arbitrary (nonempty) topological spaces and let $\operatorname{Top}(A, B)= \{ f: A \longrightarrow B \ \mid\ \text{f is continuous}\}$ be equipped with the compact-open topology. The universal property of the product allows us to find a bijective map:
$$\varphi: \operatorname{Top}(X,Y \times Z) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Top}(X,Y) \times \operatorname{Top}(X,Z)$$
We are interested in whether $\varphi$ is a homeomorphism.
I could not prove that $\varphi^{-1} =: \psi : \operatorname{Top}(X,Y) \times \operatorname{Top}(X,Z)  \longrightarrow \operatorname{Top}(X,Y \times Z)$ is continuous, or equivalently that $\varphi$ is an open map.
The question is discussed here, here and here, but provided references and proofs rely on defining a compact space as a Hausdorff space whose open covers have finite subcovers.
I am quite sure that in the above generality we do not have a homeomorphism. If we make additional assumptions on $X$, e.g., $X$ locally compact or Hausdorff, $\varphi$ can be proven to be a homeomorphism. Seen here in the case of $X$ being Hausdorff.
I am greatly interested in finding a counterexample where $\varphi$ isn't a homeomorphism. The same goes for a potential proof of $\varphi$ being a homeomorphism under the given definition of compactness.
If you decide to reference anything stating that this is indeed a homeomorphism, please check the definition of compactness beforehand or whether it's used as a Hausdorff space in the proof.

[Edit: This does not work, see the comments. Leaving it here in case anyone can get some ideas from it.]
Isn't this true in general? On the level of continuous functions we have a bijection
$$
\phi : \operatorname{Hom}(X, Y \times Z) \to 
\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y) \times \operatorname{Hom}(X,Z)
$$
given by $\phi(f) = (\pi_Y \circ f, \pi_Z \circ f)$, where $\pi_Y$ and $\pi_Z$ are the projections. Let's first prove that this is a continuous function in the compact-open topology. For this it's enough to prove that the function $\operatorname{Hom}(X, Y \times Z) \to 
\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$ given by $\psi(f) = \pi_Y \circ f$ is continuous; we can then conclude by symmetry and the product of continuous functions being continuous.
Let then $K \subset X$ be compact and $U \subset Y$ be open, and let $V(K,U) = \{ f : X \to Y \mid f(K) \subset U\}$ be an element of the subbase of the compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)$. The inverse image of this under $\psi$ is
$$
\begin{align*}
\psi^{-1}(V(K,U))
&= \{ g : X \to Y \times Z \mid \pi_Y \circ g(K) \subset U \}
\\
&= \{ g : X \to Y \times Z \mid g(K) \subset U \times Z \}
\\
&= V(K, U \times Z),
\end{align*}
$$
which is an element of the subbase  of the compact-open topology on $\operatorname{Hom}(X,Y\times Z)$. As any open set is generated by the subbase, we see that $\psi$ is continuous.
The inverse of $\phi$ is $\phi^{-1}(f,g) = f \times g$.
Let again $K \subset X$ be compact and $U \subset Y \times Z$ be open.
The topology on $Y \times Z$ is generated by products of open sets in $Y$ and $Z$, so we may assume $U = V \times W$ where $V \subset Y$ and $W \subset Z$ are open. Now
$$
V(K, V \times W)
= \{ f : X \to Y \times Z \mid f(K) \subset V \times W \}.
$$
If $f(K) \subset V \times W$ then $\pi_Y \circ f(K) \subset V$, and similarly for $Z$. Then
$$
(\phi^{-1})^{-1}(V(K, V \times W))
\subset V(K,V) \times V(K,W).
$$
Now let $f \in V(K,V)$ and $g \in V(K,W)$.
Then $(f\times g)(K) \subset V \times W$ and $\phi^{-1}(f \times g) = (f, g)$, so the inclusion above is an equality.
But then $\phi^{-1}$ is also continuous and $\phi$ is a homeomorphism.

„we may assume $U= V\times W$“, this assumption uses following result: Let $A,B$ topological spaces, where $A$ is Haussdorff and $\mathcal{S}$ a subbasis of $B$. Then sets of the form$ V(K,U)$, where $K\subset A$ and $U\in S$, form a subbasis of the comapct open topology on $Top(A,B)$. So either you have to prove, that this result works without the assumption, of $A$ being Hausdorff. Or make your proof work for any open set in $Y\times Z$, which would be an arbitray union of the basis elements.

I’m sorry, which part needs one space to be Hausdorff? One uses a description of a basis of the product topology, and the other is the definition of the compact-open topology. What am I missing?

You just proved continuity of the inverse function, whilst only paying attention to sets of the form, $V(K,U)$, $K \subset X$ compact and $U\subset Y\times Z$ and U being a basis element of the product topology. This is not sufficient, because not all subasis elements of $Top(X,Y \times Z)$ have this form. This is due $X$ not being Hausdorff. This is what my aforementioned result states. One has to prove it for $U=\bigcup_\limits{i\in I}V_i \times W_i$, $V_i\subset Y$ open and $W_i \subset Z$ open.

Ah yes, I see where it goes wrong. Proving that the inclusion is an equality no longer works. If this fails it probably fails when there aren't very many "small" open sets in the topology. Maybe taking $X = Y = Z$ as an infinite set with the cofinite topology gives a counterexample?

I would need to try it out. For the time being, could you put a disclaimer on your answer, so people won‘t mistake it for a proof, which I didn‘t accept?

Yeah, done. I played with this some more but don't have anything to show either way. It's a fun problem, I'll keep looking at it.
